# Listen to localhost messages

Tags: localhost, tcpip, ipv4, client-server

Suppose a TCP/IP client application has connected to a certain port on a server.

Both client and server are operating on localhost.

Is it possible for another application (also on localhost) to listen to the messages sent by the client to this port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you mean by "listen".

You can configure wireshark to [sniff on the Loopback interface](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback), for capturing packets in an Interprocess Communications flow, or for services addressing 127.0.0.1.

That said, you still need to be able to decode the binary serialized data, which may be non-trivial if the processes are communicating non-text data. If the data is a [stream of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) however, most sniffers decode to [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and/or [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) automatically when you look at the packets data.

Sniffer-like products are your only option however. Ports are exclusive to the process that creates them, so unless the server was designed to be accessible to multiple apps via a broker program of some sort (a connection pool for instance) , ports cannot be monitored by external programs. The only exceptions are systems software, using a driver to bypass large chunks of the OS TCP/IP stack (as a sniffer does, by reading directly off the network card, and using its own TCP/IP code to analyze the data structure). That means that you would have to perform a [TCP hijack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_sequence_prediction_attack) (a Man-in-the-middle attack) which is very difficult to perform against a modern TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Thank you, this -> "Ports are exclusive to the process that creates them" is exactly the info I was looking for. Not the answer I wanted mind you, but that's another story.

Comment: yep, I'm afraid TCP goes to some lengths to prevent non-parties from interfering with the communication and programs always need to exclusively lock their IO stream in order to be assured that only they can buffer and manipulate it at any given instant. That's not to say a MITM is entirely impossible, nor that software couldn't be designed to allow other applications to request access to its IO resources like the port, but without facilities specifically provided by the server application, you would have to resort to exploits. in the long run (your needs aside) this is probably a good thing.